# How to delete a record from a table having two primary keys?

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-delete

I have been trying to delete a record from a table using sql and delete statement but it is not working. I observed that that there are two primary keys on the table. How can i resolve this issue.

The code below shows the description. **filename** is **deletestudentsubject.php**

```
<?php 
     $name=$_REQUEST['student_id'];
     $query=mysql_query ("delete   from  studentmark
 where studentmark.CODE='$id1'  AND studentmark.student_id='$name'");   
 header('location:homet.php?action=studentsubject'); 
     ?>
     <div class='footer'>
  <p><center>
```

below code name here is studentsubject
code

```
 <?php 
$sel=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentmark");
echo '<table class="out">';
echo '<th>Year</th><th>Term</th><th>Code</th><th>Student Name</th><th>Cont Ass</th><th>1st Asg</th><th>2nd Test</th><th>Exam</th><th>Total</th><th colspan=1>ACTION</th>';

while($fetch=mysql_fetch_array($sel)){

echo '<tr><td>'.$fetch['YEAR'].'</td><td>'.$fetch['TERM'].'</td><td>'.$fetch['CODE'].'</td><td>'.$fetch['student_id'].
'</td><td>'.$fetch['ContAss20'].'</td><td>'.$fetch['AsgClassWk10'].'</td><td>'.$fetch['Test2nd10'].'</td><td>'.$fetch['Exam60'].'</td><td>'.$fetch['Total'].'</td><td><a href=modifyst.php?id='.$fetch['student_id'].'><img src="../images/edit-icon.png" width=20 height=20 title=MODIFY_RECORD /></a></td><td><a href=deletestudentsubject.php?id='.$fetch['CODE'].'><a href=deletestudentsubject.php?id='.$fetch['student_id'].'><img src="../images/edit-icon.png" width=20 height=20 title=DELETE_RECORD /></a></td></tr>';

}
echo '</table>'
```

on the phpmyadmin table on deleting it says:
Do you really want to execute "DELETE FROM `newschool`.`studentmark` WHERE `studentmark`.`CODE` = \'AGR2\' AND `studentmark`.`student_id` = \'john\'"?

both `CODE` and `student_id` are primary keys in the table structure.

Comment: Besides the fact that your code might me suspectible to SQL injection, do you get any error in your PHP script? Have you opened a connection to the database with `mysql_connect()` in the `deletestudentsubject.php` file before?

Comment: How can both code and student_id be primary keys? That is not possible.  Do you mean that they form a compound primary key? What does the second code example have to do with your question? Where is `$id1` in your first code example derived from. Have you considered adding error handling around your DB requests? Have you considered using mysqli or PDO instead of the deprecated mysql extension?

Comment: I think your problem have something with CASCADE. I assume that your primary key has Foreign relations. by default that is set to On Update or On DELETE your database to RESTRICT. This means if you have data related to primary key, you won't be able to delete any thing either from database directly or from your code. you can do it in 2 ways 1. empty foreign relations data OR 2. change RESTRICT to CASCADE it should to the job

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the primary keys are compound primary key. I am not an expert in php and my sql. pls can you tell me how  to change restrict to cascade. thanks